# Logic behind a function

Tags: c++, function

I want to understand what this function does, the logic behind it.

I've searched every term on its own (ex: `size_t`, `bitset`...) but I still want to know how the logic flows?

```
size_t popcount(size_t n) {
    std::bitset<sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT> b(n);
    return b.count();
}
```

Comment: just do more of that "searched every term on its own"

Answer (score 3):

Returns the number of bits in the bitset `b` that are set (i.e. have a value of 1).

```
size_t popcount(size_t n)
```

Passes `n` as the number of bits to be set in an bitset.

```
std::bitset<sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT> b(n);
```

Creates a `std::bitset`

```
return b.count();
```

Check the **[documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)** for `std::bitset` to see what `std::bitset::count` returns and that answers your question. As you see `std::bitset` is a standard library provided template class for storing bits.Once you understand that rest is pretty much loking in to the documentation to know what functionality this class provides and mapping it to how your code uses it.

Comment: what do you think @Sara learns from having you provide such answer. i'll tell you what: she (or he) learns that it's not necessary to do any work on your own. just post a question about any trivia on SO, and let ALS answer it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I hope it does now. I understand what you are trying to say but my guess is the OP does not understand what `std::bitset` is and hence the question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: You've been here awhile; just about everyone coming in is seeking knowledge of some sort.  Why is it a problem to provide that knowledge, and further, where do you draw the line?  Don't answer - The general consensus since [tag:homework] was deprecated is that we only draw the line by the rules in the FAQ.  The vast majority of questions asked each day on this site could have been answered if it was googled.  Heck, I bet I've answered a couple hundred questions that way myself.

Comment: @ChrisLively: I think ALS did a fine job of bringing his answer around, but you missed it. the question is, why is it a problem to provide the more valuable knowledge, that facts can be found in documentation and by googling etc., that thing things can be understood, and so on? i think the answer to the first involves SO's rep score system, and the answer to the second involves SO's lack of support and active removal of reasoning. so, the *impression* of a world of isolated facts that can only be communicated and not reasoned out, and that only can be valued by authority, is IMHO designed in.